# Laravel Undefined constant with angularjs ng-repeat error

Tags: angularjs, laravel, laravel-blade

Hi I have problem with blade how to pass `ng-repeat` array variable in function

my code is

```
<tr ng-repeat="prod in product">
    <td>@{{ prod.id }}</td>
    <td>@{{ prod.item_name }}</td>
    <td>
        <img width="50" height="50" alt="" 
         src="{{ ProductController::getProductImage(prod.id) }}"
         class="img-responsive">
    </td>
</tr>
```

any solution thanks

Comment: Can you please give  plunker link ?

Answer (score 0):

You are getting that error because

```
<img width="50" height="50" alt="" 
         src="{{ ProductController::getProductImage(prod.id) }}"
         class="img-responsive">
```

the php is executed only once and php isn't aware of the constant `prod.id`

Comment: Hi linktoahref Thanks for answer but problem is i tried {{ ProductController::getProductImage(1) }} which return me image but when i use angularjs variable @{{prod.id}} or {{prod.id}} it not gives me 1 value which makes problem with {{ ProductController::getProductImage(@{{prod.id}}) }} i tried all alternatives no success. any help will be appreciated

Comment: @user8448661 `{{ ProductController::getProductImage(@{{prod.id}}) }}` won't work as you are trying to pass JavaScript variable to php function. What you could do is use php to loop through the products in your controller.

Comment: if i use php then there is no need to use angularjs it means angularjs not support laravel..?

Comment: It is about usage of variables, not about angularjs support for laravel

Comment: Yes but there must be method to assign that variable to php or any other method..?

Comment: The issue is you are calling an php function in a javascript loop, which won't work

Comment: i think if i use javascript function to get the image will be ok thanks for your comments

Answer (score 0):

This code, `src="{{ ProductController::getProductImage(prod.id) }}"`, which is PHP/Laravel, won't work because it's running in angular/javascript. The best you can do is move that piece to Product model as a dynamic field (assuming that product is a model). After that you can use it like:

```
<img width="50" height="50" ng-src="product.image" class="img-responsive">
```

Comment: Hi Murwa ! i need prod.id as the function works when i use                          {{ ProductController::getProductImage(1) }} it return image but the angular code i tried @{{prod.id}} also {{p.id}} it show error ..

Comment: That's blade, right? Then we need to look at the order or execution...blade runs, then sends the processed html to the browser, where angular bootstraps and compiles the html. That's why `{{ ProductController::getProductImage(1) }}` works. When u use `@{{}}`, you're telling blade not to parse that, but will strip the  `@`, which will make interpolation for angular, that's y `{{p.id}}` does not work, you don't have a constant `p` defined; and neither is `p.id` php code. So u get an error in blade. Could you share the code you have for `getProductImage ` function?